# What does $N=max\{N', N_0\}$ mean?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, notation

How would you read the following and what does it mean?

$$N=max\{N', N_0\}$$

Comment: $N$ is the maximum of the set $\{N',N_0\}$, i.e. $N=N_0$ if $N_0\ge N'$ and $N=N'$ if $N'>N_0$.

Comment: My wild guess is the biggest of $N(t_0)$ and $\partial_t N$

Comment: What is going on with these tags

Comment: @qbert sorry, not an expert on what field of mathematics this would be classed as, what did i do wrong?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks, but why the inclusive sign for only one of the two values?

Comment: @Gurjinder Because if $N'=N_0$ it doesn't matter which one you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would read it in context:

"Let $N$ be the maximum of $N'$ and $N_0$."

Sometimes, I say "Let $N$ be the larger of $N'$ and $N_0$," or even better, "Let $N$ be the larger of the two."